# Where to request for new Glass voice trigger command?

Tags: android, google-glass

The category of Glass application that I am working on does not fall into any item in the current [list of voice trigger commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/app/VoiceTriggers.Command).

Is there an official way of submitting a request for a new voice trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a link on [the glassware checklist](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/checklist#d5) to the [form for suggesting new voice commands](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/voice-form).